# Generalised Stirling number that each partition has more than one component

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

We know that the Stirling number of the second kind is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty subsets and is denoted by $s(n,k)=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-j}\begin{pmatrix}
k\\ 
j
\end{pmatrix}j^n$

This formula is for the case that the partitions have at least one component. I am trying to find the similar formula for the case that each partition has at least $m$ component. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This [OEIS link](https://oeis.org/A059022) has data including generating functions and recurrence relations for the case $m=3$ which should help to get started and generalize to other values for $m.$

Comment: $\{1,\cdots ,n \} = \cup_{i=1, \cdots,k}^{\bullet} P_i$ ... each of the sets $P_i$ contains at least one element & you require them to contain at least $m$ elements. Right ? ... If so it is related to the Bell Polynomials & Faa Di Bruno Formula ... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula ... truncate the tuples at from $1$ to $m-1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Associated_Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question you should be asking is where does the formula

$$ s(n,k) = \frac1{k!} \sum_{j = 0}^k \binom{k}{j} j^n (-1)^{k - j} $$

come from? Then once you understand that, perhaps you will be able to generalize.

---

Note that the generating function for nonempty sets is $e^x - 1 = x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots$. The generating function for a set of size $k$ is $x^k/k!$. Thus the generating function for a set of size $k$ whose elements are non-empty sets is

$$ \sum_{n \ge 0} s(n,k)\frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{(e^x - 1)^k}{k!} $$

and therefore

$$ \sum_{k \ge 0} \sum_{n \ge 0} s(n,k)\frac{x^n}{n!}y^k = \exp(y(e^x - 1)). $$

Therefore

\begin{align}
  s(n,k) &= \left[ \frac{x^n}{n!}y^k \right] \exp(y(e^x - 1)) \\
 &= \frac{1}{k!} \left[ \frac{x^n}{n!} \right] (e^x - 1)^k \\
 &= \frac{1}{k!} \left[ \frac{x^n}{n!} \right] \sum_{j = 0}^k \binom{k}{j} e^{jx}(-1)^{k - j} \\
 &= \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{j = 0}^k \binom{k}{j} j^n(-1)^{k - j}.
\end{align}

---

Let us agree to write $s_m(n,k)$ for the number of ways to partition a set of size $n$ into $k$ subsets of size at least $m$.

Then the same thing happens as before except instead of using $e^x - 1$ for non-empty sets, we use $$ e^x - 1 - x - \frac{x^2}{2!} - \dots - \frac{x^{m - 1}}{(m - 1)!} = \frac{x^m}{m!} + \frac{x^{m + 1}}{(m + 1)!} + \frac{x^{m + 2}}{(m + 2)!} + \cdots $$
for sets with at least $m$ elements. So we have

$$ \sum_{n,k} s_m(n,k)\frac{x^n}{n!}y^k = \exp \left[ y \left( e^x - 1 - x - \frac{x^2}{2!} - \dots - \frac{x^{m - 1}}{(m - 1)!} \right) \right]. $$

And like before,

\begin{align}
 s_m(n, k) &= \frac{1}{k!} \left[ \frac{x^n}{n!} \right] \left( e^x - 1 - x - \frac{x^2}{2!} - \dots - \frac{x^{m - 1}}{(m - 1)!} \right)^k \\
&= \frac{1}{k!} \left[ \frac{x^n}{n!} \right] \sum_{i + j_0 + \dots + j_{m - 1} = k} \binom{k}{i,j_0,\dots,j_{m-1}} e^{ix}(-1)^{j_0}\left( -x \right)^{j_1} \cdots \left( -\frac{x^{m - 1}}{(m - 1)!} \right)^{j_{m - 1}}
\end{align}

Now we group together the minus signs: $(-1)^{j_0 + \dots + j_{m - 1}} = (-1)^{k - i}$ giving

\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{k!}\left[ \frac{x^n}{n!} \right] \sum_{i + j_0 + \dots + j_{m - 1} = k} \binom{k}{i,j_0,\dots,j_{m-1}} e^{ix}(-1)^{k - i}\left( x \right)^{j_1} \cdots \left( \frac{x^{m - 1}}{(m - 1)!} \right)^{j_{m - 1}} \\
&= \frac{n!}{k!} \sum_{i + j_0 + \dots + j_{m - 1} = k} \binom{k}{i,j_0,\dots,j_{m-1}} \frac{1}{0!^{j_0}\cdots (m-1)!^{j_{m - 1}}} [x^n] e^{ix}(-1)^{k - i} x^{0j_0 + \dots + (m - 1)j_m} \\
&= \frac{n!}{k!} \sum_{i + j_0 + \dots + j_{m - 1} = k} \binom{k}{i,j_0,\dots,j_{m-1}} \frac{1}{1!^{j_1}\cdots (m-1)!^{j_{m - 1}}} [x^{n - 1j_1 - \dots - (m - 1)j_m}] e^{ix}(-1)^{k - i} \\
&= \frac{n!}{k!} \sum_{i + j_0 + \dots + j_{m - 1} = k} \binom{k}{i,j_0,\dots,j_{m-1}} \frac{1}{1!^{j_1}\cdots (m-1)!^{j_{m - 1}}} i^{n - j_1 - 2j_2 - \dots - (m - 1)j_{m - 1}} (-1)^{k - i}.
\end{align}

Comment: What do you mean by $\binom{k}{i,j_0,\dots,j_{m-1}}$? And is the summation over the solutions of the equation?

Comment: @Hamed Yes, all solutions to the equation with $i, j_0, \dots, j_{m - 1} \ge 0$ (although by definition that symbol is zero if $i, j_0,\dots,j_{m - 1}$ don't sum to $k$ or are not all non-negative. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312648/what-does-a-binomial-coefficient-with-commas-mean).